# Why is RandomNumberGenerator.Fill used instead of RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I was browsing .NET Core Source code and i came across [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L2299-L2332) piece of code.

If the `NETCOREAPP` flag is true the code is basically this

```
private static char GetRandomRecoveryCodeChar()
{
  // Based on RandomNumberGenerator implementation of GetInt32
  uint range = (uint)AllowedChars.Length - 1;

  // Create a mask for the bits that we care about for the range. The other bits will be
  // masked away.
  uint mask = range;
  mask |= mask >> 1;
  mask |= mask >> 2;
  mask |= mask >> 4;
  mask |= mask >> 8;
  mask |= mask >> 16;

  Span<uint> resultBuffer = stackalloc uint[1];
  uint result;

  do
  {
    RandomNumberGenerator.Fill(MemoryMarshal.AsBytes(resultBuffer));
    result = mask & resultBuffer[0];
  }
  while (result > range);

  return AllowedChars[(int)result];
}
```

Why isn't the method implemented with something which is appearently simpler like this?

```
private static char GetRandomRecoveryCodeChar()
{
  int rInt = RandomNumberGenerator.GetInt32(0, AllowedChars.Length);

  return AllowedChars[rInt];
}
```

Where's the catch?

Comment: IMHO the question would have been better on the github issue page, as we can only assume what the mind process of the original author of the code was, git blame brought this up: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/pull/40723